# Why are there scripting languages running on web servers?

Tags: javascript, php, web, scripting

Can't help myself, but why are there scripting languages such as PHP running on webservers? Why not compiler languages like C? What's the advantage of using a script language on a webserver? Just heard that the biggest part of Facebook was written in PHP. Afterwards the developers introduced HipHop as a Compiler for translating into C.
Why didn't they start to program in C?

Same for client based scripting. What's the reason for using interpreted languages?

Comment: PHP and JavaScript are not interpreted languages, they are compiled to bytecode.

Comment: Perhaps because scripting languages allow easy code changing without the need to compile and link whenever you need to change anything.... they're quick and easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In big conclusion - its more convenient.

Here your can find short and nic article with advantages:
[link](http://www.serverschool.com/server-software/advantages-of-server-side-scripting/)

Answer (score 2):

Economics. Computer time is cheap. Programmer time is not.